# Как удалить обьект в Java

Tags: java, libgdx

Я создал выстрел пули:

```
for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
    bullet.x = bullet.x + 10; 
    System.out.println(bullet.x);
    batch.draw(tbullet, bullet.x, bullet.y);
}
```

Как удалить объект(пулю), когда она вылетает за экран?

Дополнение:

```
for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
    bullet.x = bullet.x + 10;
    System.out.println(bullet.x);
    batch.draw(tbullet, bullet.x, bullet.y);
    if (bullet.x>=500) {
        tbullet.dispose();// Картинка Освобождаеться
        bullets.remove(bullet);// Вызывает ошибку
    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:265)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java - язык с автоматическим управлением памятью. Поэтому явно вручную освободить память, выделенную для объекта, нельзя.

Вы можете удалить объект из коллекции `bullets`:

```
bullets.remove(bullet);
```

и тогда, если на него не осталось других ссылок, сборщик мусора когда-нибудь почистит его.

---

Если пуль много, и они появляются и исчезают очень часто, вы можете захотеть держать конечное количество пуль всегда в памяти в некотором пуле (коллекции) и добавить им поле `boolean active`. После этого вместо создания новой пули - брать из пула любую неактивную пулю и выставлять ей `active = true`. Когда пуля должна быть удалена - сбрасывать поле `active` в `false`.

Comment: Спасибо протестирую

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: В следующий раз оформляйте отдельный вопрос. `ConcurrentModificationException` говорит о том, что вы удаляете элемент коллекции внутри цикла. Так делать нельзя, используйте для этого Iterator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re

Comment: Спасибо протестирую

Comment: Все работает спасибо

Comment: У меня получилось так   for (Iterator<Bullet> iterator = bullets.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
   Bullet bullet = iterator.next();
   if (bullet.x>=500) {
    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
    iterator.remove();
   }
  }

Answer (score -3):

У меня получилось так:

```
for (Iterator<Bullet> iterator = bullets.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Bullet bullet = iterator.next();
    if (bullet.x>=500) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```